# Getting the width of a ScrollView and detecting the ends of it

Tags: android, ios, react-native, use-ref

My main initial goal is to detect the ends of the ScrollView so that I can blur the inner elements as they reach the ends, I have somewhat of an idea of how to get there, but I'm stuck at the beginning of trying to get the width of the container and the items.

Looking through a couple of past items it looks like I should just be able to useRef and then call

> componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x for position on horizontal scale

> componentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width for element width

but getBoundingClientRect shows undefined for me even though componentRef.current gives me the correct component.

I've also seen onContentSizeChange being thrown around and tested that out, but the method does not get triggered I'm guessing because the size of the content doesn't actually change for me, all of it is already rendered.

Can anyone help me out with how I can grab the width/position of elements?

[image]

Comment: l  would just wrap the `ScrollView`  in a `FrameLayout`. Put a view between the `ScrollView`; left and right thus blur one of the view accordingly.

Comment: @Darkman can you elaborate on where you would put the new View? It sounds like you are suggesting two different scrollviews? Also, just did a quick search, seems like FrameLayout is an android-only solution

Comment: Uh..my bad. Should've read the tags first. `FrameLayout` is basically a stack layout. Because of that, these two new views will overlap on top of the `ScrollView`. And No!, just a single `ScrollView` is more than enough.